# Whats the fastest in javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, function

I was wondering which of the following is faster:

Calculate when call the function:

```
isOnAir: function()
{
    return (this.velocity.y != 0)
}
```

On the update function:

```
//When input happens
this.velocity.y = CONST_SPEED;
this.isOnAir = true;
```

I've been using a lot of functions like the first one. I started seeing functions like this when programming on ruby and it just feels like the code is cleaner to me. But I'm wondering if it's cost more to do it this way.

Thanks for help/info :)

Comment: Try http://jsperf.com/

Comment: http://jsperf.com/ use this tool: check by yourself

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a performance related question that can be measured directly by the person asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

The speed of your tests may vary depending on the javascript engine you use (browser).

Answer (score 0):

You should put the velocity properties directly on the object to avoid the obnoxious pointer chasing:

```
return this.velocityX !== 0;
```

You should use a strict equality check (`!==` instead of `!=`) - a strict check will always be at least as fast so there is no reason to use `!=`.

You should definitely not add a field like `.isOnAir`: it is much harder to maintain because everywhere you change velocity you need to remember to change that field as well. It also wastes memory, which in turn actually means worse performance because it creates more work for the garbage collector.

Comment: Yeha I have the this.velocity inside the object. Yeah I always thought of doing the first one to be more practical. Thanks.